# How Can I Customize Date Format

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2005

One of my table column's named "SetDate" of type DateTime looks as:

```
2010-08-02 02:55:58.420
```

The DateTime format from the application looks as:

```
2/11/2010
```

The problem is:

I'm passing an SQL query to the DB via application. The query has WHERE clause
which compares SetDate to the date coming from application.

SetDate column carries this format: `2010-08-02 02:55:58.420`
Date passed from application carries this format: `3/12/2010`

I just need to compare the two dates without the time `2010-08-02` and `3/12/2010`.
Since they are in different formats, I get no records back from the database.

I'm using C# and T-SQL.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the application not allow you to send parameterized queries?

Comment: How are you constructing the query in your app? Store proc? Parameterized query?...

Comment: In my case, i'm hard coding the query temporarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   YourTable 
WHERE 
   RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(19), SetDate, 101)) = '3/12/2010'
```

Comment: By running the coversion on the column, rather than on the passed in value, there's no possibility of an index being usable. In addition, if you're going to compare dates as strings, it's a lot better to use a language neutral format (e.g. YYYYMMDD), which would again point to a conversion of the passed in value anyway.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the index issue, thanks for pointing that out. However, if the query needed to obtain records for a particular date, regardless of the time, I'd think you'd still need to run a conversion on both the column and the passed in value. Otherwise you'll need to query for items between the min date/time and max date/time for the same day (which may be better since you can take advantage of the index).

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a SqlCommand to run your query?

Yes? Also use SqlParameters for you users/system input.

```
var setDate = DateTime.Now();

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableX WHERE SetDate > @SetDate", connection))
{
    // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SetDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, setDate));
    // Read in the SELECT results.
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    //More code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On you WHERE clause for the DATETIME in the Database you need to do something like this.
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), '2010-08-02 02:55:58.420'))

Answer (score 0):

In your Where clause, you can use the `Date` member of the DateTime class `DateTime.Now.Date`. It returns the date without the time.

As long as you work with Date Objects (.net or SQL server), the format doesn't matter, as it's your job to parse the string to object or reverse, internally the format is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to run DB queries from code is to call stored procedures, if possible.  However, whether you're doing that, or not, you'll want to use the `SqlParameter` object initialized with the date you need.

```
DateTime dateToCheck = DateTime.Now;
using(SqlCommand cmd //Set Command Here)
{
  cmd.CommandType = SqlCommandType.Procedure;
   //Doing this from memory, but that line should be pretty close
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateToCheck", dateToCheck);

  //Continue with call to DB as normal
}
```

One not here, some people do specify the type of "DateTime" on their `SqlParameter` object, but I've never done that, and it hasn't come back to bite me, yet.  I believe (again, operating off memory here) that if you're using a System.[whatever] type, SqlParameter can automatically assign it to the correct Sql type.  So passing in a string may still yield a string, but passing in a DateTime will yield a DateTime.